# Reading a messy CSV file

Tags: java

So the program is supposed to read a DanceName that you enter in TUI, read two csv files which follows the idea of: DanceName(\t)(any amount of spaces) Performer/groupName,(space or no space)Performer/groupName. If after the DanceName there is a groupName, it is supposed to go to another CSV file and read all of the performers in the groupName. If after a comma there is a space after the performer, it works fine. But if there isnt one it just prints the groupName

```
public String listAllDancersIn(String dance) {
    // get CSV file for dances Data


    Set<String> dancesData = new TreeSet<>(getCSV("src/csvFiles/danceShowData_dances.csv"));
    String result = "";

    // for each line in dances csv file
    for (String line : dancesData) {

        // split into two sections - [0] is name of dance & [1] is dancers
        String[] splitByTab = line.split("\t");

        splitByTab[0] = splitByTab[0].trim();

        // if name of dance matches given dance name
        if (splitByTab[0].equals(dance)) {

            // split names of dancers into individual strings
            String[] separatedNames = splitByComma(splitByTab[1]);

            // iterate through names
            for (int i = 0; i < separatedNames.length; i++) {
                // append result with output of getDanceGroupMembers (and trim input)
                result += ", " + getDanceGroupMembers(separatedNames[i].trim());
            }
        }
    }

    // remove leading comma and space
    result = result.substring(2);

    return result;
}

public String[] splitByComma(String names) {
    return names.split(", ");
}

public String getDanceGroupMembers(String name) {
    // get dance group data

    Set<String> danceGroupsData = new TreeSet<>(getCSV("src/csvFiles/danceShowData_danceGroups.csv"));

    // result by default is just name of given
    String result = name;

    // iterate iterate
    for (String line : danceGroupsData) {
        String[] splitByTab = line.split("\t");

        // if, at any point, name of dance group is equal to given name
        if (splitByTab[0].equals(name) ) {
            // return names of dancers in group 
            result = getDanceGroupMembers(splitByTab[1]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tip: [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/csv/) project.

Comment: Thank you! This seems very useful for future, we are forced to use this method for university though @BasilBourque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If after a comma there is a space after the performer, it works fine.
>   But if there isnt one it just prints the groupName.

That's because you are doing,
`names.split(", ");` and not `names.split(",");`

What you should be doing is,

1. Split on Comma using `names.split(",");`
2. Trim the whitespaces using `trim()`.